# XML detect the content of multiple children and delete parent based on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Some Title</title>
        <pubDate>1/1/17 00:00:00</pubDate>
        <generator>SomeOne</generator>
        <item>
            <title>
                Some Item Title 1
            </title>
            <link>http://example.org</link>
            <description>
                Lorem ipsum ...
            </description>
            <pubDate>1/1/17 00:00:00</pubDate>
            <category>Cat1</category>
            <category>Cat2</category>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>
                Some Item Title 2
            </title>
            <link>http://example.org</link>
            <description>
                Lorem ipsum ...
            </description>
            <pubDate>1/1/17 00:00:00</pubDate>
            <category>Cat2</category>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>
                Some Item Title 3
            </title>
            <link>http://example.org</link>
            <description>
                Lorem ipsum ...
            </description>
            <pubDate>1/1/17 00:00:00</pubDate>
            <category>Cat1</category>
        </item>
        ....
        ....
        ....
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I am using this `jQuery` code to remove the parents:

```
var myCat = 'Cat1';
rss.find('item').find('category').filter(':not(:contains('+ myCat +'))').parent().remove();
```

Now the problem is, As you can see in my provided xml that. Single, `<item>` contains 2 `<category>` and one of those is a match for `myCat` but that `<item>` is still removed, whilst it shouldn't be. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzkd7o2o/)

P.S. From given example, only the 2nd `<item>` should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop over your items and see if each one contains your cat:

```js
var str = `<?xml version='1.0'?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Some Title</title>
        <pubDate>1/1/17 00:00:00</pubDate>
        <generator>SomeOne</generator>
        <item>
            <title>
                Some Item Title 1
            </title>
            <link>http://example.org</link>
            <description>
                Lorem ipsum ...
            </description>
            <pubDate>1/1/17 00:00:00</pubDate>
            <category>Cat1</category>
            <category>Cat2</category>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>
                Some Item Title 2
            </title>
            <link>http://example.org</link>
            <description>
                Lorem ipsum ...
            </description>
            <pubDate>1/1/17 00:00:00</pubDate>
            <category>Cat2</category>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>
                Some Item Title 3
            </title>
            <link>http://example.org</link>
            <description>
                Lorem ipsum ...
            </description>
            <pubDate>1/1/17 00:00:00</pubDate>
            <category>Cat1</category>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>`;

var rss = $.parseXML(str);
rss = $(rss);

var myCat = 'Cat1';
rss.find('item').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('category:contains('+ myCat +')').length == 0){
    $(this).remove();
  }
});

console.log(rss.find('item').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```